# Scikit-learn SVM: Reshaping X leads to incompatible shapes

Tags: python, error-handling, scikit-learn, svm

I try to use scikit-learn SVM to predict whether a stock from S&P500 beats the index or not.
I have the 'sample' file from which I extract the features X and the labels (beats the index or doesn't beat it) Y.

When I tried it the first time (without reshaping X) I got the the following depreciation error:

```
DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 
and will raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using
X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) 
if it contains a single sample.
```

Consequently I tried the reshaping of X according to the recommendation and also to some forum posts.
Now however I get the following value error that X and Y don't have the same shape.

```
ValueError: X and y have incompatible shapes.
X has 4337 samples, but y has 393.
```

Below you can see the shapes of X and Y before reshaping:

```
('Shape of X = ', (493, 9))
('Shape of Y = ', (493,))
```

and after reshaping:

```
('Shape of X = ', (4437, 1))
('Shape of Y = ', (493,))
```

I also tried to reshape so that I get the (493,9) shape, but also this didn't work as I got the following error.

```
ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged.
```

I posted below the code to extract the features and labels from the pandas DataFrame and and the SVM analysis:

Feature & Label selection:

```
X = np.array(sample[features].values)
X = preprocessing.scale(X)    
X = np.array(X)    
X = X.reshape(-1,1)    

Y = sample['status'].values.tolist()
Y = np.array(Y)

Z = np.array(sample[['changemktvalue', 'benchmark']])
```

SVM testing:

```
test_size = 50

invest_amount = 1000
total_invests = 0
if_market = 0
if_strat = 0    



clf = svm.SVC(kernel="linear", C= 1.0)
clf.fit(X[:-test_size],Y[:-test_size])

correct_count = 0

for x in range(1, test_size+1):
    if clf.predict(X[-x])[0] == Y[-x]:
        correct_count += 1

    if clf.predict(X[-x])[0] == 1:
        invest_return = invest_amount + (invest_amount * (Z[-x][0]/100)) #zeroth element of z 
        market_return = invest_amount + (invest_amount * (Z[-x][1]/100)) #marketsp500 is at pos 1

        total_invests += 1
        if_market += market_return
        if_strat += invest_return

print("Accuracy:", (float(correct_count)/test_size) * 100.00)
```

Would be great if you have any inputs on how to solve this.

Comment: I think you should just `reshape((-1,1))` on `Y` and read about broadcasting rules...

Comment: that's exactly the problem, that this reshaping didn't work as it lead to the value error above

Comment: You shouldn't be reshaping. Reshaping is only when you have a single feature as evident from the warning. But you have 9 features in `X`. Remove the `reshape` in your code and post the whole stack trace.

Comment: If I don't do the reshaping I get the DepreciationWarning. And what exactly do you mean by the stack trace?

Comment: I am sorry, that's a warning not an error, so no stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be reshaping `X` to `(-1, 1)`. In fact the error is in your call to the `predict` method.

Change

```
clf.predict(X[-x])[0]
```

to

```
clf.predict(X[-x].reshape((-1, 9)))[0]
```

Comment: I tried your predict version, but it gives me a syntax error:    `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: mhm it still doesn't work and gives me `ValueError: X.shape[1] = 1 should be equal to 9, the number of features at training time` also when I try different reshaping I get errors

Comment: Yes, the number of features must be 9 so reshape it to `(-1, 9)`, see my edit.

Comment: ah I changed it only in one of the two predicts to 9 first, now it works. thank you so much for your support!!